# How should I do this query in Sqlite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a database with the columns: id, pdate, pvalue1, pvalue2. First I make a query with a cursor:

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { "_id","pdate","pvalue1","pvalue2"},
                    "pdate >= ? AND pdate <= ?",  new String[] { datefrom, dateto }, null, null, null);
```

This gives me some rows, for example if pdate = 20120318, then pvalue1 = 58, pvalue2=29. These are strings so I can give a value of "XX" to pvalue2. I would like to sum the pvalue1 between the given datefrom and dateto and group them by pdate where pvalue2 = XX. My problem is that I cannot put this condition into the query (with that its working, like "pvalue2 = XX"..), because I need the other datas too.

```
if (c.moveToFirst())
{
     do{
         if (c.getString(3).equals("XX")){
         Log.i("XX", c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2)) + " " + c.getString(3));

          }
         else {
         Log.i("NotXX",  c.getString(1) + " " + c.getString(2)) + " " + c.getString(3));

          }

     while (c.moveToNext());
     }
}
```

It is okay so far, so I can log the datas with this where pvalue2 = XX and NotXX and get something like this:
(pdate,pvalue1,pvalue2)     20120317,48,29;------;20120317,21,54;-------20120317,11,XX;-----20120318,79,71;-------20120318,21,XX;

What I would like to do?

First: Grouping the sums (pvalue1) by pdate and indicate it if pvalue2 is XX or notXX, so somethnig like this:
20120317,NotXX,69 (since 48+21=69) --------  20120317,XX,11 -------- 20120318,NotXX,79 -------- 20120318,XX,21

After this I would like to substract the XX sum from the NotXX sum for every day. I would like to get:
   20120317,58  (since 69-11)    ------- 20120318,58   (since 79-21)

How sould I do this?
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that I cannot put this condition into the query

You are probably wrong. You can add something like (syntax may contain errors)

"select sum(select pdate from DATABASE_TABLE where pdata > x and pdate < y) as sum"

to the projection argument and you get that result as a column named sum. The only problem is that there is no support for `?` in projection (at least I have not tried it but I guess it would not work)

If that's not what you want then there is very likely a different way. SQLite is very powerful.

Edit:

Would that be what you want? It's not done in SQL but it would print the sum you want for each day.

```java
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { "_id","pdate","pvalue1","pvalue2"},
        "pdate >= ? AND pdate <= ?",  new String[] { datefrom, dateto }, null, null, "pdate");
boolean first = true;
if (c != null) {
    String currentDate = null;
    int sum = 0;
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String date = c.getString(1);
        int value1 = c.getInt(2);
        String value2 = c.getString(3);
        if (!date.equals(currentDate)) {
            if (!first) {
                Log.d("TAG", "The result for " + currentDate + " is: " + sum);
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "Date has changed, but we don't have data yet.");
            }
            first = false;
            currentDate = date;
            sum = 0;
        }
        if ("XX".equals(value2)) {
            Log.d("TAG", "new line: " + date + ", " + value1 + ", " + value2 + " -");
            sum -= value1;
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "new line: " + date + ", " + value1 + ", " + value2 + " +");
            sum += value1;
        }
    }
    if (!first) {
        Log.d("TAG", "The last result: " + currentDate + " is: " + sum);
    }
    c.close();
}
```

Edit2: This might work when you want it done by the database.

```java
Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(
        "SELECT pdate, sum(sum2) AS sum1 FROM " +
        "(" +
        "   SELECT pdate, pvalue1, pvalue2, -sum(pvalue1) AS sum2 " +
        "      FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE +
        "      WHERE pvalue2='XX' GROUP BY pdate" +
        "   UNION " +
        "   SELECT pdate, pvalue1, pvalue2, sum(pvalue1) AS sum2 " +
        "      FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + 
        "      WHERE pvalue2!='XX' GROUP BY pdate" +
        ") " +
        "   WHERE pdate>=? AND pdate<=? " +
        "   GROUP BY pdate",
        new String[] { datefrom, dateto });
if (c != null) {
    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        String date = c.getString(0);
        int value1 = c.getInt(1);
        Log.d("TAG", "The result for " + date + " is: " + value1);
    }
    c.close();
}
```

Comment: Many other query contains ? in my project so its not a problem. For example I can use :  new String[] { "_id","pdate","sum(pvalue1)", },
     "pdate >= ? AND pdate <= ?",  new String[] { datefrom, dateto }, "pdate", null, null);  This gives me the sum of pvalue1 for every day. But I cant use this, because I have to seperate XX and Notxx values.

Comment: yes, `?` in the `selection` argument works if you specify them in `selectionArgs` but I meant putting `?` in `projection`. It may work but I believe it does not. Would require [prepared statements](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29) probaly

Comment: `db.query("table", new String[] { "_id", "sum(select pdate from table where pdate > ?) as sum"}, "pdate >= ? AND pdate <= ?",  new String[] { /* projection ? maybe here, */ datefrom, dateto }, null, null, null);` that's about what I mean

Comment: With this, I am not sure what to write for the projection .

Comment: Could you try to explain what you try to get out of the database? With a written table of how you want the result to look like. That's the part I still don't really understand. My answer so far was more like "SQLite can do so much that there is probably a way to do it with a single query"

Comment: I wrote it in the first comment. There is an example for it. I would like to get only one value for every day. Substract the sum of pvalue1 datas where pvalue2 is XX from the  the sum of pvalue1 datas where pvalue2 is NOT XX. I'm pretty sure it can be done with sqlite, but I just dont know how :)

Comment: I've added some code to my answer which I believe is what you want to do. Is the part that prints correct? If so maybe I can find an SQLite statement that does this.

Comment: I dont get anything for tagging, I am not sure why.

Comment: I am a beginner, but where do you change the currentDate string? It is always null as I see.

Comment: I somehow dont get anything to log :S

Comment: Ok, added some debug. Do you get anything now? If not then the cursor is null or empty and you need to check that the query is correct / the database is filled.

Comment: Yes I get something: First: "Date has changed, but we don't have data yet."); Then I get all the datas, so with 3 values in a day, I get three more rows.  BUT: all the rows end with '+'. I debugged it before and got the sum but there were no substractiod, it added all the ints together

Comment: My fault, so the substraciton is okay ,I get the rows with the suitable ending

Comment: Wow, it is almost good. So I only get the sum for 20120317 if I set 20120317 to 20120318 in datefrom and dateto. But at least the data is ok what I get :)

Comment: What is funny as hell that the main problem was "XX".equals(value2) does work while values2.equals("XX") does not. :)

Comment: that's maybe because `String oops = null;` `"XX".equals(oops)` works, while `oops.equals("XX")` will give a NullpointerException. Also I've played around with SQLite, see Edit2